# Japanese Fulltext Search RoR Postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, full-text-search

I'm trying to get japanese fulltext search working in postgresql. I found some projects like acts_as_ludia and textsearch_ja. But they all seam outdated. Does anyone have any information on other japanese fulltext search libs?

Comment: Can you elaborate on why PG's built-in [full text search](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch.html) is not suitable for your case?

Comment: There are no japanese dictionaries for PG's built in full text search. At least I didn't find any of them.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Laszlo from the Hunspell project, I found a japanese dictionary in here http://cgit.freedesktop.org/libreoffice/core/tree/i18npool/source/breakiterator/data/ja.dic

Answer (score 0):

The big problem with using Japanese and tsearch2 is that tsearch2 requires that languages be separated by whitespace between words and Japanese does not do this.  However according to http://www.sai.msu.su/~megera/postgres/gist/tsearch/V2/docs/tsearch2j.html there are libraries available to make the conversion (these could be hooked into PostgreSQL through appropriate language functions).  He then mentioned he had to modify some other things and his code is no longer available but off-hand I can't think of any reason you couldn't use simple dictionaries on Japanese at that point (you'd lose stemming and stop words) but that should get you going.